# An if/else issue in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

For a project I'm working on, I'm making a simple text-based adventure. At one point, the user sees two keys and a door nearby. I'm trying to make it so that if the user enters the door without both keys, it opens up the frame where it states that they will need both to open it (Frame 11).

The problem is, whether or not the user grabs them, it automatically directs them through the door as if they have opened it (Frame 12).

Here's my total coding. Don't mind commented portions, that's just me trying out some different approaches.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
var torchb: Boolean = false;
var redkeyb: Boolean = true;
var bluekeyb: Boolean = true;

stop();

StartButtonInst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Page2);

function Page2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(2);
    LeftButtonInst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Page3);
    RightButtonInst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Page4);

}

function Page3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(3);
    GoBack1Inst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Page2);

}


function Page4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(4);
    WalkOffInst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Page5);
}

//function torch (e:MouseEvent){

    /*if(torchb == true){
    this.removeChild(GrabTorchInst);
    this.gotoAndStop(7);
}
else{
    this.gotoAndStop(6);
} */


    /*if(!torchb) {
        torchb = true;
        this.removeChild(GrabTorchInst);
        //this.gotoAndStop(7);
    }
    else {
        torchb = false;
        this.gotoAndStop(6);
    }*/

//GrabTorchInst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, torch); 
//This event should change the boolean if the torch is picked up

//EnterCaveInst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cave); 
//This event should change the frame to the cave or not depending what the torch bool is.

function torch (e:MouseEvent) {
torchb = torchb==true?false:true;
    this.removeChild(GrabTorchInst);
    }

function cave(e:MouseEvent) {
if(torchb) {

this.gotoAndStop(7);
    }
else {
this.gotoAndStop(6);
    } 

}


function Page5(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(torchb);
    gotoAndStop(5);
    GrabTorchInst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, torch);
    EnterCaveInst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cave); 

    //GrabTorchInst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Page5);
    EnterCaveInst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Page7);

    /*if (GrabTorchInst = true)
    {
        this.gotoAndStop(7);
    } */
}   
/*function torch (e:MouseEvent){

    if(!torchb) {
        torchb = true;
        this.removeChild(GrabTorchInst);
        this.gotoAndStop(7);
    }
    else {
        torchb = false;
        this.gotoAndStop(6);
    }
}*/

function Page6(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(6);
    GoBack2Inst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Page5) 
}

function Page7(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(7);
    LightTorchInst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Page8)
    AssassinateInst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Page10)
}

function Page8(Event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(8);
    AssassinateInst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Page10)
    RunAwayInst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Page9)
}

function Page9(Event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(9);
    GoBack3Inst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Page7)
}

/*function redkey (e:MouseEvent){
    if(!redkeyb) {
        redkeyb = true;
        this.removeChild(RedKeyInst);
        //this.gotoAndStop(12);
    }
    else {
        redkeyb = false;
        this.gotoAndStop(11);
    } 
} */

function redkey (e:MouseEvent) {
redkeyb = redkeyb==true?false:true;
    this.removeChild(RedKeyInst);
    }

function bluekey (e:MouseEvent) {
bluekeyb = bluekeyb==true?false:true; 
    this.removeChild(BlueKeyInst);
    }

function door(e:MouseEvent) {
    if(redkey==true && bluekey==true){
        (12) 
this.gotoAndStop(12);
}
else {
this.gotoAndStop(11);
    }
}
/*function bluekey (e:MouseEvent){
    if(!bluekeyb) {
        bluekeyb = true;
        this.removeChild(BlueKeyInst);
        //this.gotoAndStop(12);
    }
    else {
        bluekeyb = false;
        this.gotoAndStop(11);
    }
} */

if(redkey==true&&bluekey==true){
    (12) 
    }

function Page10(Event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(10);
    RedKeyInst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, redkey)
    BlueKeyInst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bluekey)
    DoorInst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, door)
    DoorInst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Page12)

}

function Page11(Event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(11)
    GoBack4Inst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Page10)
}

function Page12(Event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(12)
    GiveJakeAnAInst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Page13)
}

function Page13(Event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(13)
}
```

I'd really appreciate some assistance on this.

Comment: Need more information. What do you initialize torchb as. It seems you initialize torchb as false meaning when ever the torch event runs it will always send them to the 7th frame.

Comment: I did in fact initialize it as false, under the premise that the cave should not be entered until it is picked up. However, I realized that I don't have anything in my coding that will change the statement to true upon picking it up. Do you happen to know how to change the boolean? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is what you want but you can try

```
if(torchb == true){
    this.removeChild(GrabTorchInst);
    this.gotoAndStop(7);
}
else{
    this.gotoAndStop(6);
}
```

So if torchb is true, they would be sent to 7th frame
if it isn't, they would be sent to sixth frame.

Comment: I like the idea, but it seems to give the reverse issue. I think I see the problem though. Upon picking up the torch, the boolean doesn't change to true. I'm fairly novice, so I don't know how to fix that. Would you mind helping me go about it?

Comment: How do you check to see if the player picked up the torch?